# Persistence of object instantiated in method and added to Collection in C#

Tags: c#, object, garbage-collection, scope, persistence

I understand that objects are reference types and that when they are added to a list or a dictionary say, we are just adding a reference to the actual object. However, what I am struggling to understand is, why, once the object is instantiated in a method and added to a list, it doesn't go out of scope once the method is run?

I think this code should explain better what I mean:

```
public class Program
{
    public List<SomeObject> myList = new List<SomeObject>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.AddStuffToList();

        // Why do the items in the list still exist?
        foreach (var i in p.myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void AddStuffToList()
    {
        // this object is scoped to this method, so when I add it to the list, why does it still exist once outside the method?
        SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
        obj.Name = "test";
        myList.Add(obj);
    }
}

public class SomeObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object `obj` itself is scoped to `AddStuffToList` method. However, `myList` which is a class variable contains a reference to the object itself.
What's getting "out of scope" is only `obj` which is a refernce to your object

Therefore the garbage collector doesn't collect your object (`myList` still reference to it).

In `AddStuffToList` your memory looks like this:
[image]

And when `AddStuffToList` exits only `obj` is collected:
[image]